# Rename variables for multiple dataframe, using a loop, referencing the dataframe names from a list

Tags: r, parsing

Difficult to articulate. Here is an example to explain.
I have 3 dataframes.

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c(1:5),var2=seq(1,10,by=1) )
df2 <- data.frame(var1=c(6:10),var2=seq(1,10,by=1) )
df3 <- data.frame(var1=c(11:15),var2=seq(1,10,by=1) )
```

I have a list with those dataframe names

```
df_list <- c("df1","df2","df3")
```

I'm trying to rename the all the variables within each of those dataframes to be "VALUE"
I can do it for each dataframe with a line of code like this

```
names(df1)[1:ncol(df1)]<-paste("VALUE")
```

Sometimes I may have several dataframes. Rather than write hundreds of lines of the same code, I'd like to do this with a loop. I tried this but without luck.

```
for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
 
  names(get(df_list[i]))[1:ncol(get(df_list[i]))]<-paste("VALUE")
  
  }
```

Is there a way of doing this with a loop? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Expected output would be VALUE as variable name for all variables in each dataframe

```
> df1
   VALUE VALUE
1      1     1
2      2     2
3      3     3
4      4     4
5      5     5
6      1     6
7      2     7
8      3     8
9      4     9
10     5    10
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Note from `?names`: 'value - a character vector of up to the same length as x, or NULL.'

Comment: Sidenote: `df_list <- c("df1","df2","df3")` is a character vector, not a list containing `df1, ...`

Comment: i've edited with expected output. All the dataframes to have same variable/column name "VALUE"

Comment: response to sidenote - i know. it's a character list, with the names of the dataframes

Comment: Any time you have names like `xxx1`, `xxx2`, you should probably be using a list. Why not just `df_list[[1]] <- ...`, `df_list[[2]] <- ...` and then run `df_list <- lapply(df_list, ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the values of the object names with `mget` into a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, set the column names to `rep`licated 'VALUE' (not recommended at all - as `data.frame` column names should be unique)

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(df_list), function(x) setNames(x, rep("VALUE", ncol(x))))
```

Comment: Never thought to do it this way with mget, I can work with this. I understand not recommended but this is first part of my code where later I'm going to append a unique name (such as V1,V2) to the "VALUE" to make them unique "V1 VALUE". I have to repeat the process for different classes of variable with "PERCENT", "INDEX" etc and also append V1,V2 etc to them to make unique. Many thanks for the help

Comment: @H.Cheung or you can make use of `make.unique` i.e. `setNames(x, make.unique(rep("VALUE", ncol(x))))`

Answer (score 2):

There are probably good reasons not to name all your columns the same, but a nested loop works:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c(1:5),var2=seq(1,10,by=1) )
df2 <- data.frame(var1=c(6:10),var2=seq(1,10,by=1) )
df3 <- data.frame(var1=c(11:15),var2=seq(1,10,by=1) )

df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
for (j in 1:length(names(df_list[[i]]))) {
names(df_list[[i]])[j] <- 'VALUE'
}
}

str(df_list)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ VALUE: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ VALUE: num [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ VALUE: int [1:10] 6 7 8 9 10 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ VALUE: num [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ VALUE: int [1:10] 11 12 13 14 15 11 12 13 14 15
  ..$ VALUE: num [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

It can be done, but should it?